# That all people might believe through 'him' - who is 'him'? John 1:7

Tags: john

NKJV John 1:7

This man came for a witness, to bear witness of the Light, that all through him might believe.

MEV John 1:7

This man came as a witness in order to testify concerning the Light, that all men through Him might believe.

I don't understand why MEV capitalized Him?

Now I'm confused whether John 1:7 is talking about John or Jesus?

I've always believed it's John.

Comment: The natural antecedent of 'him' is 'light' (which has already been personalised in verse 3) and then a further, definitive, statement follows 'he was not that light' emphasising the antecedent. There follows another definitive statement about the 'true light' and its universal application (regarding 'all humanity' - or 'every man'). I do not see why you think that 'all through him might believe ' refers to John.

Comment: Because NKJV uses "Him" (capital H) while refering to Christ but it does not in John 1:7. And even NLT reads God sent a man, John the Baptist, to tell about the light so that everyone might believe because of "his testimony." (John was the one testifying...so...)

Comment: All men, through Christ, believe in (what?).

Comment: All men, through John, believe in Christ.

Comment: The latter makes more sense to me.

Comment: It refers to John. So either this version mistakenly think it refers to Jesus or they think John's pronoun should be capitalized. Maybe it is a Johnian religion.

Answer (score 1):

The question essentially reduces to finding the antecedent of "him" (αὐτοῦ) the last word in John 1:7.

The answer to this question becomes clearer when the overall outline of the section is observed:

- John 1:1-5 - about Jesus
- John 1:6-8 - about John the Baptist
- John 1:9-13 - about Jesus

Now let us examine a literal translation (BLB) of John 1:6-8

- V6: There came a man having been sent from God. His name - John.
- V7: This one came as a witness, that he might testify concerning the Light, that all might believe through him.
- V8: He was not the Light, but [came] that he might witness concerning the Light.

Thus, the antecedents of all the pronouns here is John the Baptist as confirmed by V8; ie, it cannot be Jesus because Jesus, the Word, is the Light and V8 says that "he" was not the light.  That "he" and "him" must be John the Baptist.

The "*believing through him*" is direct reference the explicitly stated purpose of the ministry of John the Baptist as "*preparing the way for the Lord*", Matt 3:3, Mark 1:3, Luke 3:4.  That is, without John the Baptist's preparatory work, Jesus ministry would have been much less effective.

Compare this with Ellicott's remarks:

> (John 1:7) **For a Witness**.—Stress is laid upon the work of John as
> “witness.” This was generally the object of his coming. It was
> specially to “bear witness of the Light.” The purpose of testimony is
> conviction “that all men through him might believe,” i.e., through
> John, through his witness.

Meyer is similar:

> **διʼ αὐτοῦ** by means of John, so far as he by his witness-bearing was the medium of producing faith: “and thus John is a servant and
> guide to the Light, which is Christ” (Luther); not by means of the
> light (Grotius, Lampe, Semler), for here it is not faith in God (1
> Peter 1:21) that is spoken of.

The Cambridge commentary is similar:

> through him] i.e. through the Baptist, the Herald of the Truth. Comp.
> John 5:33; Acts 10:37; Acts 13:24.

I am at a loss to understand why the MEV, almost alone (I could find no others) capitalizes "Him" in John 1:7.

Answer (score 1):

The Greek text (PT punctuation) is:

> οὗτος ἦλθεν εἰς μαρτυρίαν,
>  ἵνα μαρτυρήσῃ περὶ τοῦ φωτός, 
> ἵνα
> πάντες πιστεύσωσι διʼ αὐτοῦ.

The *him* in διʼ αὐτοῦ (*di autou*) is genetive masculine.  The *Light* (φωτός - *phōtos*) is neuter, so διʼ αὐτοῦ cannot refer to it.

The phrase pretty clearly refers to John, not Jesus.  This is the way the Greeks read it, in any case.  See, for example, [John Chrysostom's commentary](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf114.iv.viii.html).

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow the context and derive the meaning from that.

> In Him was life, and the life was the light of men... v4

We know that this is not yet speaking of Jesus, but the logos from preceding verses.

> 6There came a man having been sent from God. His name was John. 7He came as a witness, that he might testify concerning the Light, that **all** might believe through him. 8He was not the Light, but came that he might witness concerning the Light.

> 9The **true Light who enlightens every man** was coming into the world. 10He was in the world, and the world came into being through Him, and the world did not know Him. 11He came to the own, and the own did not receive Him. 12But as many as received Him, He gave to them authority **to be children of God—to those believing in His name**, 13who were born not of blood, nor of will of flesh, nor of will of man, but of God.

- Jesus is the representative of God being the light, the logos and the one with authority.
- John is bearing witness of the light.
- Without the light, no man can see or believe.
- Jesus is the one through whom ALL (as bolded v7) will believe - they will see by the light which Jesus provides - the truth, the power, the sacrifice etc.
- ALL are not believing in John! His impact was on a very small group of his day and has no bearing on "ALL".
- John bore witness to that one who is the light - that ALL might believe through him - Jesus.
- "*But as many as received Him*" v12 We cannot *receive* unless we first know who we are receiving. This is not possible from within the world, but from God alone - He makes His son known and brings them to true life through him.
- part of that journey requires a firm belief - certainly not in John, but only in Jesus.

John's role was to point toward Jesus, *not* so that ALL might believe because of him, but because of the one he witnessed of - that ALL might believe in Jesus, and the One who sent him, and finally be born of God.
(John 3:2, 5:19, 10:38, 14:11)